# Add a custom path to jenkins node's sh path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to add a custom path to my jenkins node path so that when I execute a `sh` command from a pipeline script it includes a given PATH directory.

I go to the node properties and specify the following, which appears valid according to the little '?' tooltip.

The executable I want to have on my Jenkins node path is inside the `/Applications/zconbt/bin` directory.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is correct! In order to a custom path to `PATH` you have to set the `Name` as `PATH+MY_LOCAL_PATH` then when you print the `PATH` value inside the pipeline it will contain the path you wanted

```groovy
script {
    sh 'echo $PATH'                             
}
```

Result:

```
/my/custom/path:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Aha - thats true, and has apparantly worked, however, whenever I try to execute my binary, which is inside my folder which is now on the path, it isn't resolved, I have to hardcode the entire path! Any ideas why?

Comment: I executed `whereis` on a command in custom path and it worked correctly, maybe you have permissions issue in case you are using non-root user

Comment: but as long as it appears in your `PATH` and the file is executable it should work